# Запрос на непрерывность данных

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день!
Есть таблица table с тремя полями: id, value, date. value>=0. Нужно выдать группы последовательных value > 0. Пример: value: 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4. В этом случае вывести: группа 1: 1,2; группа 2: 3,4. Есть подозрения использовать оконные функции, но не уверен... в какую сторону смотреть?

Answer (score 1):

```
select grp, value
  from (
    select *,
           sum(mark) over(order by date)+1 grp,
           lead(value) over(order by date) next
      from (
        select *,
               case when value!=lag(value) over(order by date)+1 then 1 else 0 end mark
          from Q where value>0
      ) X
  ) Y
where mark=0 or value=next-1
```

Вводим поле mark, которое принимает значение 0 если предыдущее значение на 1 меньше текущего и значение 1 если это не так. Кумулятивная сумма этого признака обеспечивает нам нумерацию групп подряд идущих значений, так как она увеличивается, переключая номер группы, в случае если последовательность нам не подошла. Так же этот признак используется позже, что бы выдавать записи перед которыми были подходящие, дополнительно смотрим следующее значение, что бы вывести те записи, за которыми еще есть подходящие.